# Route53 health check for A records with the same record name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, health-check

I have multiple A records in Route53 with the **same record name** pointing to **different URLs** with latency routing. Is it possible to use the same health check ID (i.e. same domain) for each record or do I need to create a separate health check per URL?

```
A records:

api.mydomain.com => subdomain1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (latency)
api.mydomain.com => subdomain2.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com (latency)

Health check:

api.mydomain.com
```

According to this setup, would AWS intelligently route traffic to the API Gateway URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your health check is pointing to `api.mydomain.com`, the behavior will not be deterministic. You cannot know where the health check is executing from, so you do not know which endpoint will be checked. If your goal is to ensure that both subdomains are healthy, you should set up health checks for each subdomain.